# ajustar tamaño de pagina al achicar la ventana

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

He visto en muchas paginas que al achicar la ventana aunque sea hasta 1024px de ancho el contenido de la pagina se achica acorde al tamaño de la ventana intente con media queries pero no entendi muy bien como usarlo soy nuevo en esto de css les dejo el código

gral.css

```css
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

body {
 /* background-image: url("../rock.jpg");*/
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

main {
 width:70%;
 float:left;
 background-color: #fff;
 height: auto;

}

aside{
 width: 30%;
 float:right;
 background-color: #fff;
 height: auto;
}

.glyphicon {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.icon-size
{
    font-size: 87px;
}

.container{
 float:left;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

/* NavBar gral*/
.navbar {
 border-bottom:2px solid #F49D51;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* NavBar login de usuario*/
.navbar-login
{
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-login-session
{
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

/* Manejo de Tabs Gral*/
.tabss{
 background-color: #444444;
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 border-bottom-color: #666666;
}

.nav-tabs {
 margin-left: 5px;
 border: 0px solid transparent;
 
}

.nav-tabs > li > a,
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
    color: #FFF;

}
.nav-tabs > .open > a,
.nav-tabs > .open > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > .open > a:focus,
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #666666;
 border-color: transparent;
 
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #666666;
 border-color: #444444;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.panel-primary {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-top-color: #666666;
  float:left;
  width:95.8%;
}

.panel-primary > .panel-heading {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666666;
  border-color: #666666;
}


.panel {
   border: 0px solid transparent;
}

.panel-heading {
   border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;
   width: 100%
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 15px; 
  float:left;
}
/* Fin Panel Tabs Gral*/

.top-aside{
 float:right;
 background-color: #444444;
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 border-bottom-color: #666666;
 border-left-color: black;
 box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #3a3a3a inset;
 height: 46px;
 width:100%;
}
/* Mesas Restaurant */
.table-mesas {
 float:left;
 width: 95.8%;
}
.table-mesas tr td{
 padding:15px;
} 
.butt-mesas {
 -webkit-border-radius: 4;
 -moz-border-radius: 4;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #666666;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 30px 40px;
 background:  #88dd77;
 border: solid #000000 1px;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%;
}

.butt-mesas:hover {
 background: #9ae288;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #666666;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/* Fin Mesas Restaurant */
```

```html
<html lang="es">
  <head>
<title>Trabajo Cuatrimestral OO2</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/gral.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</script>
  </head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../logo.jpg" width="150" height="35"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active" id="restaurant"><a href="../restaurant/salon.html" title="Restaurant"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span></a></li>
      <li id="ventas"><a href="#productos/" title="Ventas"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
      <li id="productos"><a href="../productos/productos.html" title="Productos"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple"></span></a></li>
      <li id="client"><a href="#productos/" title="Clientes"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
      <li id="report"><a href="#productos/" title="Reportes"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span></a></li>
      <li id="config"><a href="#productos/" title="Configuración"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
          <strong>Nombre</strong>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="navbar-login">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <p class="text-center">
                    <img src="../foto-carnet.jpg" width="100" height="100">
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <p class="text-left"><strong>Nombre Apellido</strong></p>
                  <p class="text-left small">correoElectronico@email.com</p>
                  <p class="text-left">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">Actualizar Datos</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <div class="navbar-login navbar-login-session">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tabss">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="../restaurant/salon.html">Salon</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Salon 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <span class="panel-title">MESAS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table-mesas">
            <tr>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
              <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <section class="top-aside">
    </section>
  </aside>
</body>

</html>
```

si quieren ver bien el diseño les dejo mi bootstrap.css porque cambie partes del mismo sin saber y sino no se aprecia el diseño

bootstrap.css
https://mega.nz/#!Fj5GWLBL!4wNXxG65pFD9IOr9rum6UTUCKWrv9eN-TpXt8QDVHSw

bootstrap.css.map
https://mega.nz/#!1vZQWCxY!AArlqs4Eyngz0HrXi2AC0gSWphzcPhwIe18E7Hm2ilQ

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir también los media queries que has intentado utilizar?

Comment: No deberías cambiar las bibliotecas estándar, sino crear tus propios ficheros separados que las extiendan/complementen. Esos cambios solo dificultan el mantenimiento y la depuración del código. Sé que no ayuda mucho con el problema actual, pero nos/te será de gran ayuda en el futuro.

Comment: Gracias alvaro si me di cuenta tarde que me convenia cambiarlo en una hoja de estilos aparte el tema es que como no entendia bien los selectores era mas facil ir probando en bootstrap cual era y ahora si pongo el bootstrap.css estandar se rompe el diseño voy a ver si lo puedo arreglar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Te dejo un ejemplo tal vez sea lo que quieras

```css
.maxWidth {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.header__logo {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px;
}
.header__menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.header__menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main__content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 500px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main__content {
    width: 70%;
  }
  .main__aside {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header maxWidth">
  <div class="header__logo">Logo</div>
  <nav class="header__menu">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<section class="main maxWidth">
  <div class="main__content"></div>
  <aside class="main__aside">
  </aside>
</section>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.maxWidth {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.header__logo {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px;
}
.header__menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.header__menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main__content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 500px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main__content {
    width: 70%;
  }
  .main__aside {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header maxWidth">
  <div class="header__logo">Logo</div>
  <nav class="header__menu">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<section class="main maxWidth">
  <div class="main__content"></div>
  <aside class="main__aside">
  </aside>
</section>  
</body>
```

Gracias era exactamente lo que buscaba me podrias explicar lo que hacen estas lineas de css

display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

es lo unico que no entiendo lo voy a googlear igual pero si me podes explicar mejor.

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: el display: flex; es un modelo de cajas flexibes y las otras propiedades como aligns-items y justify-content es para centrar los elementos dentro del  div padre, deberia aprender a usar display flex y display grid ya que esto es  lo mas actual para grids con css.